# Set the adapter to spinner using 3rd party API

Tags: android, arraylist, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner, onitemselectedlistener

I'm using [this](https://github.com/miteshpithadiya/SearchableSpinner) 3rd party library for searchable spinner. Every thing is good but problem is that when I set the adapter to the spinner so in the drop-down I'm getting object reference instead of string. The array-list filled by web services using retrofit library.

Below is my activity:

```
countriesCustomAdapterInr = new CountriesCustomAdapterInr(getActivity(), R.layout.custom_spinner_items, arrayList,res);
spinner.setAdapter(countriesCustomAdapterInr); 

spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ""+arrayList.get(i).getFull_name()+i, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

                            }
                        });
```

This is my model class:

```
public class CurrencyConverter {

    @SerializedName("short_name")
    private String short_name;

    @SerializedName("full_name")
    private String full_name;

    @SerializedName("flag")
    private String flag;

    public CurrencyConverter(String short_name, String full_name, String flag) {
        this.short_name = short_name;
        this.full_name = full_name;
        this.flag = flag;
    }

    public CurrencyConverter() {}

    public String getShort_name() {
        return short_name;
    }

    public void setShort_name(String short_name) {
        this.short_name = short_name;
    }

    public String getFull_name() {
        return full_name;
    }

    public void setFull_name(String full_name) {
        this.full_name = full_name;
    }

    public String getFlag() {
        return flag;
    }

    public void setFlag(String flag) {
        this.flag = flag;
    }

}
```

My Adapter:

```
public class CountriesCustomAdapterInr extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private ArrayList data;
    public Resources res;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public CountriesCustomAdapterInr(
            FragmentActivity activitySpinner,
            int textViewResourceId,
            ArrayList objects,
            Resources resLocal)
    {
        super(activitySpinner, textViewResourceId, objects);

        data     = objects;
        res      = resLocal;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activitySpinner.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    private View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_spinner_items, parent, false);

        CurrencyConverter tempValues = null;
        tempValues = (CurrencyConverter) data.get(position);

        TextView label        = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textView_short_name);
        TextView sub          = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textView_full_name);
        ImageView flag = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imageView_flag);
        TextView line = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.row);
        if(position==0){
            label.setText("INR");
            sub.setText("India");
            flag.setImageResource(R.drawable.ind);
            line.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else
        {
            // Set values for spinner each row
            label.setText(tempValues.getShort_name());
            sub.setText(tempValues.getFull_name());
            Picasso.with(getContext()).load("http://currencyconvertor.ccube9projects.com/uploads/country_flag/"+ tempValues.getFlag()).into(flag);
        }


        return row;
    }
```

I have attached image also for the more clarification. Please anyone can help? I have wasted my 2 days but i didn't get any answer. Please help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is you can't set your own custom adapter with this library.  If you look at line 160 of his SearchableListDialog (https://github.com/miteshpithadiya/SearchableSpinner/blob/master/searchablespinnerlibrary/src/main/java/com/toptoche/searchablespinnerlibrary/SearchableListDialog.java#L160) it is always setting the adapter to a simple array adapter for Strings only.

If you want a way to actually implement what you want, you can copy his library into your code and modify what you need.  For example, changing line 160 in SearchableListDialog to be this:

```
listAdapter = new CountriesCustomAdapterInr(getContext(), R.layout.custom_spinner_items, items, getResources());
```

You will need to change your constructor for your adapter as well to this:

```
public CountriesCustomAdapterInr(
    Context context,
    int textViewResourceId,
    List<CurrencyConverter> objects,
    Resources resLocal) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);

    data = objects;
    res = resLocal;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context
        .LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
```

And finally you will need to override toString in your CurrencyConverter in order to get the search to work:

```
@Override
public String toString()
{
    return short_name;
}
```

Comment: Actually I have 2 text and 1 image in custom items list so I can't use toString(). If I have only one text then I can use toString() but customize design I can't use. Any other solution?

Comment: toString() is only to get the Search Filter to work.  Changing the library's SearchableListDialog will give you the custom adapter you want.

Comment: I don't know what you are asking.  The code above works and generates what you want.

Comment: Hello @tim.paetz I got your point. I'm getting result as I want but still one issue is here for example In search-view widget I search London, I'm not getting the result filtered as London but when clicking on the listview, results is showing item as London.It is like the position is change for the items but the list is not showing the searchable result. can you suggest me what is the problem? Please help me.

Comment: You should post another question with your code and what is wrong.

Comment: I have posted question @tim.paetz this is link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47278704/how-to-use-searchview-onquerytextlistener-in-searchable-spinner please help me.

Comment: Hello @tim.paetz Please go through on my SO question. I'm not able to find the issue. Please help me. I have wasted 4-5 days but I didn't get any solution. Please help.