# How to use SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() in searchable spinner?

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner, searchview

I'm creating a searchable spinner using third party library. I have added library classes(SearchableListDialog, SearchableSpinner) in my app. Everything is working fine but still one problem I'm facing for example, In search-view widget if I search Abc, I'm not getting the result filtered as Abc but when clicking on the list-view items, results is showing item as Abc. It is like the position is change for the items but the list is not showing the searchable result. I'm not getting where is I'm wrong. I modified code many times but didn't get desirable result.

[image]

Searchable Spinner xml code:

```
 <com.example.my.currencyconverterapp.activity.SearchableSpinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinner"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/rl_currency_converterted_data"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

This is my Fragment code where I'm setting a adapter to searchable spinner.

```
countriesCustomAdapterInr = new CountriesCustomAdapterInr(getActivity(), R.layout.custom_spinner_items, arrayList,res);
        spinner.setAdapter(countriesCustomAdapterInr);
        assert spinner != null;
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ""+arrayList.get(i).getFull_name()+i, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {}
        });
```

This is third party SearchableSpinner class:

```
public class SearchableSpinner extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner implements View.OnTouchListener,
        SearchableListDialog.SearchableItem {

    public static final int NO_ITEM_SELECTED = -1;
    private Context _context;
    private List _items;
    private SearchableListDialog _searchableListDialog;

    private boolean _isDirty;
    private ArrayAdapter _arrayAdapter;
    private String _strHintText;
    private boolean _isFromInit;

    public SearchableSpinner(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this._context = context;
        init();
    }

    public SearchableSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this._context = context;
        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.SearchableSpinner);
        final int N = a.getIndexCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
            int attr = a.getIndex(i);
            if (attr == R.styleable.SearchableSpinner_hintText) {
                _strHintText = a.getString(attr);
            }
        }
        a.recycle();
        init();
    }

    public SearchableSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        this._context = context;
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        _items = new ArrayList();
        _searchableListDialog = SearchableListDialog.newInstance
                (_items);
        _searchableListDialog.setOnSearchableItemClickListener(this);
        setOnTouchListener(this);

        _arrayAdapter = (ArrayAdapter) getAdapter();
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(_strHintText)) {
            ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(_context, android.R.layout
                    .simple_list_item_1, new String[]{_strHintText});
            _isFromInit = true;
            setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

            if (null != _arrayAdapter) {

                // Refresh content #6
                // Change Start
                // Description: The items were only set initially, not reloading the data in the
                // spinner every time it is loaded with items in the adapter.
                _items.clear();
                for (int i = 0; i < _arrayAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
                    _items.add(_arrayAdapter.getItem(i));
                }
                // Change end.

                _searchableListDialog.show(scanForActivity(_context).getFragmentManager(), "TAG");
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void setAdapter(SpinnerAdapter adapter) {

        if (!_isFromInit) {
            _arrayAdapter = (ArrayAdapter) adapter;
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(_strHintText) && !_isDirty) {
                ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(_context, android.R.layout
                        .simple_list_item_1, new String[]{_strHintText});
                super.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
            } else {
                super.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

        } else {
            _isFromInit = false;
            super.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSearchableItemClicked(Object item, int position) {
        setSelection(_items.indexOf(item));

        if (!_isDirty) {
            _isDirty = true;
            setAdapter(_arrayAdapter);
            setSelection(_items.indexOf(item));
        }
    }

    public void setTitle(String strTitle) {
        _searchableListDialog.setTitle(strTitle);
    }

    public void setPositiveButton(String strPositiveButtonText) {
        _searchableListDialog.setPositiveButton(strPositiveButtonText);
    }

    public void setPositiveButton(String strPositiveButtonText, DialogInterface.OnClickListener onClickListener) {
        _searchableListDialog.setPositiveButton(strPositiveButtonText, onClickListener);
    }

    public void setOnSearchTextChangedListener(SearchableListDialog.OnSearchTextChanged onSearchTextChanged) {
        _searchableListDialog.setOnSearchTextChangedListener(onSearchTextChanged);
    }

    private Activity scanForActivity(Context cont) {
        if (cont == null)
            return null;
        else if (cont instanceof Activity)
            return (Activity) cont;
        else if (cont instanceof ContextWrapper)
            return scanForActivity(((ContextWrapper) cont).getBaseContext());

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getSelectedItemPosition() {
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(_strHintText) && !_isDirty) {
            return NO_ITEM_SELECTED;
        } else {
            return super.getSelectedItemPosition();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object getSelectedItem() {
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(_strHintText) && !_isDirty) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return super.getSelectedItem();
        }
    }
}
```

This is third party SearchableListDialog class:

```
public class SearchableListDialog extends DialogFragment implements
        SearchView.OnQueryTextListener, SearchView.OnCloseListener {

    private static final String ITEMS = "items";

    private CountriesCustomAdapterInr listAdapter;

    private ListView _listViewItems;

    private SearchableItem _searchableItem;

    private OnSearchTextChanged _onSearchTextChanged;

    private SearchView _searchView;

    private String _strTitle;

    private String _strPositiveButtonText;

    private DialogInterface.OnClickListener _onClickListener;

    public SearchableListDialog() {

    }

    public static SearchableListDialog newInstance(List items) {
        SearchableListDialog multiSelectExpandableFragment = new
                SearchableListDialog();

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable(ITEMS, (Serializable) items);

        multiSelectExpandableFragment.setArguments(args);

        return multiSelectExpandableFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams
                .SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Getting the layout inflater to inflate the view in an alert dialog.
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());

        // Crash on orientation change #7
        // Change Start
        // Description: As the instance was re initializing to null on rotating the device,
        // getting the instance from the saved instance
        if (null != savedInstanceState) {
            _searchableItem = (SearchableItem) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("item");
        }
        // Change End

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.searchable_list_dialog, null);
        setData(rootView);

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        alertDialog.setView(rootView);

        String strPositiveButton = _strPositiveButtonText == null ? "CLOSE" : _strPositiveButtonText;
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton(strPositiveButton, _onClickListener);

//        String strTitle = _strTitle == null ? "Select Country" : _strTitle;
//        alertDialog.setTitle(strTitle);

        final AlertDialog dialog = alertDialog.create();
        dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams
                .SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
        return dialog;
    }

    // Crash on orientation change #7
    // Change Start
    // Description: Saving the instance of searchable item instance.
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putSerializable("item", _searchableItem);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
    // Change End

    public void setTitle(String strTitle) {
        _strTitle = strTitle;
    }

    public void setPositiveButton(String strPositiveButtonText) {
        _strPositiveButtonText = strPositiveButtonText;
    }

    public void setPositiveButton(String strPositiveButtonText, DialogInterface.OnClickListener onClickListener) {
        _strPositiveButtonText = strPositiveButtonText;
        _onClickListener = onClickListener;
    }

    public void setOnSearchableItemClickListener(SearchableItem searchableItem) {
        this._searchableItem = searchableItem;
    }

    public void setOnSearchTextChangedListener(OnSearchTextChanged onSearchTextChanged) {
        this._onSearchTextChanged = onSearchTextChanged;
    }

    private void setData(View rootView) {
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);

        _searchView = (SearchView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.search);
        _searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName
                ()));
        _searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
        _searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        _searchView.setOnCloseListener(this);
        _searchView.setQueryHint("Search Country");
        _searchView.clearFocus();
        InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(_searchView.getWindowToken(), 0);


        List items = (List) getArguments().getSerializable(ITEMS);

        _listViewItems = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listItems);

        //create the adapter by passing your ArrayList data
//        listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
listAdapter = new CountriesCustomAdapterInr(getActivity(), R.layout.custom_spinner_items, arrayList, getResources());
//

        //attach the adapter to the list
        _listViewItems.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        _listViewItems.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        _listViewItems.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                _searchableItem.onSearchableItemClicked(listAdapter.getItem(position), position);
                getDialog().dismiss();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onClose() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
        _searchView.clearFocus();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
//        listAdapter.filterData(s);
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(s)) {
//                _listViewItems.clearTextFilter();
            ((ArrayAdapter) _listViewItems.getAdapter()).getFilter().filter(null);
        } else {
            ((ArrayAdapter) _listViewItems.getAdapter()).getFilter().filter(s);
        }
        if (null != _onSearchTextChanged) {
            _onSearchTextChanged.onSearchTextChanged(s);
        }
        return true;
    }

    public interface SearchableItem<T> extends Serializable {
        void onSearchableItemClicked(T item, int position);
    }

    public interface OnSearchTextChanged {
        void onSearchTextChanged(String strText);
    }
}
```

Here OnQueryTextListener() not working fine. Please help me. I tried but didn't any solution. Can anyone please help me. Above, I have mentioned my query. Thanks

Comment: this is totally copy from here :https://github.com/miteshpithadiya/SearchableSpinner 
If you solve this issue : it's good for repo : https://github.com/miteshpithadiya/SearchableSpinner/issues/122

Answer (score 8):

Instead of using a Spinner with SearchView, I would suggest you to achieve this with ListView and SearchView, I tried and it works very well.

Put a button on your activity. Now clicking on this button will open a custom dialog.

[image]

Your custom_dialog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
        android:id="@+id/searchView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then set your button onClick event and do the following.

```
 @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Dialog dialog = new Dialog(SearchText.this);
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(SearchText.this);
                View view1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_search_layout, null);
                ListView listView = view1.findViewById(R.id.listView);
                SearchView searchView = view1.findViewById(R.id.searchView);

                final ArrayAdapter<String> stringArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(SearchText.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.my_currency));
                listView.setAdapter(stringArrayAdapter);

                searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String newText) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                        stringArrayAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                dialog.setContentView(view1);
                dialog.show();
            }
```

[image]

Now do your search, and add OnItemClickListener on your listview, and do whatever you want after selecting your choice.

[image]

Comment: @Kenjin You can also use Spinner in place of Listview, I tested it and it works. Let me know if you any query.

Answer (score 0):

you can search in your adapter... i didn't see your adapter
you can look my adapter 
https://github.com/kenmeidearu/SearchableSpinner/blob/master/searchablespinnerlibrary/src/main/java/com/kenmeidearu/searchablespinnerlibrary/ListAdapterSpinner.java

i give you example