# onItemClick doesn't work after creating a new Adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Actually in my app i have a recyclerView with some items in it

I also have a searchView and when i make it's empty i'm making the following actions

```
edtSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                itemAdapter.getFilter().filter(edtSearch.getText().toString().toLowerCase());
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(edtSearch.getText().toString())) {
                    itemAdapter = new ItemAdapter(InventarioActivity.this, itemModel);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(itemAdapter);
                    itemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        });
```

Till here all works fine but after i clear the text from this editText the onClick method on the recyclerView is not working anymore so i have to close and reopen my AlertDialog with that recyclerView.

Answer (score 1):

Kind of hard to say without knowing what the recyclerView adapter looks like and where the click listener lives. Could you try to remove the code posted below from the click listener and paste it before edtSearch.addTextChangedListener? That part strikes me as kind of odd.

```
itemAdapter = new ItemAdapter(InventarioActivity.this, itemModel);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(itemAdapter);
```

Edit:
TextWatcher might not be the right solution in combination with SearchView. Here's an example on how this (or something similar) could work with SearchView.OnQueryTextListener:

[Check first answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47278704/how-to-use-searchview-onquerytextlistener-in-searchable-spinner)

Comment: Actually i was invoking the click listener when i was creating the Dialog so after dismissing the search the onClick method was not considered anymore so i created a method a part and i invoke it again when the text of searchView is cleared.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not sure what you are trying to do. It probably helps if you post more of your code. But with SearchView, TextWatcher might not be the right way to go. There's an OnQueryTextListener for SearchView. Maybe give that one a try? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.OnQueryTextListener